# What does the strange syntax mean in c++

Tags: c++, syntax

In Unreal Project I have this line:

`class USpringArmComponent* CameraBoom`

and

`class UCameraComponent* FollowCamera`

And I haven't ever seen this syntax in c++. What does it mean?

Comment: What is strange for you, exactly? Did you know what pointers are, in C++? If not: consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: What part is strange to you? The pointers or the use of the word `class`? In either case I would suggest read more about C (read about `structs` instead of `classes`) because both these come from C.

Comment: This is a dark corner of the language - difficult to search for if you don't know the term. Downvotes are harsh IMHO.

Comment: I agree with @Bathsheba, this is a good question.

Comment: The `*` means the type is a _pointer_, and the _pointer_ may point to a `USpringArmComponent` type (in the first case) for the variable `CameraBoom`, or to a `UCameraComponent` type (in the second case) for the variable `FollowCamera`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just telling the compiler that `UCameraComponent` is a class. Not anything else. It's like in C you put `struct` before any structure variable declarations.

This syntax is useful when you have some messy code (or to convey that it is a class verbosely to the developer).

For example:

```cpp
class counter
{
// bla bla bla...
};

void foo()
{
    int counter = 0; // Oops someone declared a variable called counter.
                     // How am I going to declare a variable of type `counter`?4
    // counter actual_counter; // Syntax error: expected ';' after expression.
                               //Because counter is a variable
    class counter actual_counter; // You prepend `class` to the deceleration
}
```

Comment: I know. I though a beginner friendly approach would be better in this question.

Comment: Trivial edit to convert the downvote to an upvote. Sorry for trolling.

Comment: Interesting!  I did not know that!  Because I don't normally do that kind of thing.  I was able to do it this way: `class std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > s;`  But it doesn't parse with the typedef `class std::string s;`.

Answer (score 6):

It's an *elaborated type specifier*:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier

Comment: Thanks for finding the verbiage!  I didn't know what to call that syntax.